# error: too many template-parameter-lists

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors

My code;

```
template<typename T, int N>
class ngon{
  point<T> vertices[N];
  ...
  template<typename O> ngon<T,N>& operator=(const ngon<O,N> otyp);
    // O stands for other, as in other type
  ...
};

...
template<typename T, int N> typename<typename O>
ngon<T,N>& operator=(const ngon<O,N> otyp){
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    vertices[i] = point<T>(otyp.vertices[i]);
  return this;
}
```

gives the error;

```
.\Libraries/.\Geometry\Polygon_D2.hpp:103:11: error: too many template-parameter-lists
ngon<T,N>& operator=(const ngon<O,N> otyp){
```

What did I do wrong? the templating is all correct.

Comment: what's this additional `typename<O>` in `template<typename T, int N> typename<O>` ... ?

Comment: It automates type conversion

Comment: I meant the syntax. It looks like a typo, you have a `typename<O>` outside the template decl., and there is no dependent type so `typename` is not needed.

Comment: I forgot the typename in the definition. this wasn't actual code, though I had a very similar problem at one point, its just a Q-A style thing in the hopes that someone who is perplexed by their compiler's output finds this and this clears things up for them.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
ngon<T,N> ngon<T,N>::operator=(const ngon<O,N> otyp){
```

instead of

```
ngon<T,N> operator=(const ngon<O,N> otyp){
```

The compiler first takes note of the fact the operator is in the public domain and has two template-lists rather then one, instead of noting that the operator isn't valid. It then outputs the somewhat misleading error that your templating is faulty instead of detecting that the function hasn't been listed as a member-function as it should have been.

Comment: I hope this helps a few people. I always copy my class definitions and then replace relevant fields when doing lots of boilerplate code, so this kind of thing slips by me much more then I would like.